# Speeding up R filtering in loop

Tags: r, optimization

I'm running a script against ~1m records that gets an aggregation for each day in the dataset and binds it to a full dataset and it's taking a really long time. 90% of the time in each loop is spent in the filter() portion.

Is there any way to speed this up?

```
for (i in seq_along(date_range)){    
  todays_results <- state_change %>% filter(state_date <= date_range[i] & date_range[i] <= next_state_dt)
  todays_results <- todays_results %>% group_by(state_date, marketing_category) %>% count()

  daily_state_counts <- rbind(daily_state_counts, todays_results)  
}
```

Here's a sample of the data

```
 contact_id      state_date marketing_category next_state_dt next_mc  
   <fct>           <date>     <fct>              <date>        <fct>    
 1 003U000000Dyl6Z 2014-01-07 dormant            NA            NA       
 2 003U000000DylwT 2014-01-07 dormant            NA            NA       
 3 0030P00001ypDpt 2014-01-07 dormant            2014-02-12    recruiter
 4 0030P00001ypFZW 2014-01-07 dormant            2014-07-30    recruiter
 5 003U000000Io07V 2014-01-07 dormant            2017-02-13    recruiter
 6 0030P00001ypE7S 2014-01-07 recruiter          2015-07-08    dormant  
 7 0030P00001yOP1K 2014-01-07 dormant            2014-05-15    recruiter
 8 003U000000LNi2C 2014-01-07 dormant            NA            NA       
 9 003U000000DyjAb 2014-01-07 dormant            2014-11-20    recruiter
10 003U000001Z6yb6 2014-01-07 dormant            2016-01-15    recruiter
11 003U000000Oc9xR 2014-01-07 dormant            2015-10-21    inactive
```

Comment: Looks like you're growing your variable within a for-loop which causes the slow down. See this for options to improve the speed http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/

Comment: See here as well http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html

Comment: Thank you! I will apply this to solve the problem of the growing variable in the rbind() portion, however, I'm still hoping there's a way to speed up the filter(), which takes the longest time.

Comment: Can you provide some data?

Comment: Just added a data sample. Thank you.

Comment: Can you use `dput()` so that we can copy and paste it?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to avoid growing objects is to use `lapply()` and then `do.call()`.

Try

```
lapply(seq_along(date_range), function(i) {    
  state_change %>% 
    filter(state_date <= date_range[i] & date_range[i] <= next_state_dt) %>% 
    group_by(state_date, marketing_category) %>% 
    count()
}) %>%
  do.call("rbind", .)
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed the problem in the date_range varible. Will update post now.